# MYSQL trigger trouble

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to make a trigger to do this:

```
UPDATE formulario 
    SET ano = EXTRACT(year FROM create_date),
    mes = EXTRACT(month FROM create_date)
```

But i am getting a lot of trouble making it. it is accepted but doesn't work or gives away error message on posting new rows.
I want to insert the `create_date` and get the `ano` and `mes` auto fitted. how can i do this ?

sorry here is the trigger defenition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `anomes` AFTER INSERT ON `formulario` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE formulario SET ano = EXTRACT(year FROM create_date);
UPDATE formulario SET mes = EXTRACT(month FROM create_date); 
END;
```

and table:

```
-- Dumping structure for table at.formulario
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `formulario` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uniqid` varchar(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ano` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mes` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codcliente` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_act` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacto_nome` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacto_funcao` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contacto_telefone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cara_cli_abc` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cara_cli_estado` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cara_cli_tipo_est` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cara_cli_sazonal` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `loc_inst_piso` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loc_inst_acesso` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loc_inst_data_vistoria` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `loc_inst_data_inter` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `loc_inst_time_vistoria_start` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `loc_inst_time_vistoria_end` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `loc_inst_time_inter_start` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `loc_inst_time_inter_end` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `check_list_p_agua` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `check_list_t_agua` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `check_list_p_dist` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `check_list_obs` text,
  `final_obs` text,
  `vendedor` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt_aceito` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bonus` text,
  `anulado` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: How about showing your trigger definition? We're not going to write one for you, but will try to help fix what you've done so far.

Comment: What is the exact code you use? I mean the line that starts with "`create trigger`". See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Can you add table and trigger definition to your question? I hope the query your posted is not a body of trigger on `formulario` table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot modify the table that invoked this trigger. It is a restriction.

Try to use a BEFORE INSERT trigger and set new values before the inserting data. For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER anomes
BEFORE INSERT
ON formulario
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.ano = EXTRACT(year FROM NEW.create_date);
  SET NEW.mes = EXTRACT(month FROM NEW.create_date); 
END
```

And the question - why are you going to store this data in the table? You can calculate it on the fly in SELECT query.

Comment: tanks it worked out :) i only use that because e need those fields on another software that doesn't suport views or querys... just reads data as it is...